# Invalid shorthand property initializer error connecting to Mongo DB Atlas

Tags: express, mongoose, backend, mongodb-atlas

I want to connect my project to Mongo DB Atlas. It shows the following error while connecting the Database:

> ```
> me :~/Desktop/prod$ npm run server
>
> > @0.1.0 server /home/me/Desktop/
> > nodemon server.js
>
>
> [nodemon] 2.0.4 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon] watching path(s): *.* [nodemon] watching extensions:
>     js,mjs,json [nodemon] starting `node server.js` Url/keys.js:2
>     mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-ttxhq.mongodb.net/test"
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
>     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/saurabh/Desktop/prod/server.js:10:12)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> ```

My code is :

```
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI
mongoose
    .connect(db, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex : true, 
        useUnifiedTopology : true
    })
    .then(()=>console.log("Database Connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server Starter on port ${port}`))
```

keys.js file is:*

```
modules.exports = {
    mongoURI = "MONGODBURI"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

modules.exports = {
mongoURI: "MONGODBURI"
}

This is a JSON so we cannot use '=' here.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried IP whitelisting yourAtlas MongoDB cluster?

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
[Medium tutorial](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-configure-firewall-ip-whitelisting-in-mongodb-atlas-52775102ce3c#:~:text=Adding%20an%20entry%20to%20the,Click%20Save%20and%20Close.)